# Ambients from Tokyo

Tags: ambience

Hi Guys, I am now editing the sound for a documentry with some footage shooted in Tokyo, I've been looking for some ambients in my library, but still unhappy with the result.
If someone have some good material to share, would be a GREAT HELP.
As charge, i can provide some realy nice and rare sounds from Portugal (The place where i live).
If you are interessed, please contact me to gois.pedro@hotmail.com

Cheers.

Pedro.

Comment: Howdy fellow portuguese!


Comment: Where is the footage shot in Tokyo? As with any city, the soundscape can vary greatly depending on where you are. Can you give more details. 

Answer (score 2):

Hi Pedro
Surround2011 have some Tokyo ambience.

Sound or Noise Vol.1 to 4
http://surround2011.bandcamp.com/album/sound-or-noise

Blog:
http://surround2011.blogspot.com/search/label/LocationScouting
http://surround2011.blogspot.com/search/label/crowds

Search by picture:
https://picasaweb.google.com/surround2011org/ClockTower24Hours
https://picasaweb.google.com/surround2011org/LocationScouting

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I live in Tokyo and have some city sounds recorded. (Was too lazy to edit them, though xD)

If you need sounds from specific locations, I can go there and try recording somethinf interesting :D

PS
Sounds from Portugal would be nice to get :D

Answer (score 1):

Do people on this forum commonly trade these kinds of atmos sounds? Because I would love to be able to use a recording of a european outdoor market for an upcoming uni project! Anyone want some australian atmos?

Comment: For sure people request sounds! But start a new specific topic if you have a sound you're after :-) 

Answer (score 0):

I record ambiences from Saint-Petersburg and Moscow in Russia. If it may be useful, i'll upload them when i get enough interesting material (crowd, malls, subway etc).